# Checkbox Error: Too few positional arguments:

Tags: button, checkbox, dart, flutter

```
 new Checkbox (
        onChanged: (bool resp)
        {
         setState(() {
          _sel=resp;

         });
        },
        value: _sel,
      ),
```

Comment: Please add the full and exact error message.

Comment: Compiler message:
lib/MyApplication.dart:34:24: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
          new Checkbox (
                       ^
file:///C:/Users/Orbit/Downloads/Programs/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/checkbox.dart:1: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
Compiler failed on E:\q_app\lib\main.dart
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the error message there. In comments formatting gets lost.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer    I will

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Checkbox-class.html

[image]

You need to pass the required parameter `value`

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/bbb080b3a3d4e2f3b61b2f7b029cafdb9b9cab99/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/selection_controls_demo.dart#L91-L98

Comment: Yes, there are the void main

Comment: Try https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted